# How to enable OpenMP support in the Makefiles / GCC

Tags: gcc, makefile, openmp

I am trying to parallelize for loops by using OpenMP for two different projects, but OpenMP has an issue with Makefile: `ignoring #pragma omp parallelize for`. So I need to change the Makefile so it can support OpenMP but i don't know how.

```
all: lbm 

lbm: lbm.c main.c 
    gcc -o lbm lbm.c main.c -lm
clean:
    rm -f lbm *.o

all: mcf 

mcf: implicit.c  mcfutil.c  pbeampp.c  pflowup.c   pstart.c   treeup.c mcf.c       output.c   pbla.c     psimplex.c  readmin.c
    gcc -o mcf *.c 
clean:
    rm -f mcf *.o
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `gcc`, OpenMP is enabled via the `-fopenmp` flag. Add this to every invocation of `gcc`. Different compilers may use different flags, in those cases consult the compiler manual. To make sure the changes are effective, run `make clean && make all` after editing the `Makefile`.

Comment: i did that but didn't work "make: Nothing to be done for `all'."

all: lbm 

lbm: lbm.c main.c 
 gcc -fopenmp -o lbm lbm.c main.c -lm
clean:
 rm -f lbm *.o

Comment: The Makefile does not detect changes to itself. You need to run `make clean && make all`.

Comment: thank you for helping me but i new to this things will the message changed to : gcc fopenmp -o lbm lbm.c main.c -lm
gcc: error: fopenmp: No such file or directory
make: *** [lbm] Error 1

Comment: Seem you forgot about the minus sign of `-fopenmp`?

Comment: yeap that's it, thank you very much you are amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `-fopenmp` option to each call of `gcc`.

Comment: i did that but didn't work "make: Nothing to be done for `all'."

all: lbm 

lbm: lbm.c main.c 
 gcc -fopenmp -o lbm lbm.c main.c -lm
clean:
 rm -f lbm *.o